# How to set the attached Grid.Row property in ListView's item template?

Tags: xaml, winui-3

How can I set the attachaed property `Grid.Row="?"` marked beneath inside the `DataTemplate` ? So that the `ListView` will stretch the items in 5 equal rows.

```
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    </Grid>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <view:SingleChartView Grid.Row="?" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although Grid derives from Panel, it is not designed to be used as an ItemsPanelTemplate out of the box.

Old but relevant: https://blog.scottlogic.com/2010/11/15/using-a-grid-as-the-panel-for-an-itemscontrol.html

Bottom line, this somewhat requires the ability to dynamically create rows, and also apply Grid's attached properties using code behind.

Comment: I dropped ```ListView``` after all and set ```DataContext``` manually in code-behind instead. It Become as simple as 
```<Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <view:SingleChartView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="_1"/>
                <view:SingleChartView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="_2"/> ...```